# Is there a program to generate text logo for release note?

Tags: text, graphical-logo

Is there a program to generate text logo for release note, like as the following?

[image: example of text logo]

Comment: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/ first google result. With this, the question should be closed.

Comment: WoW! That's what I want. Thank you!